# In Django, how to find out if a request has been canceled?

Tags: django, http, comet

I have a view in Django which streams a response. (Think of a web-based chat circa 1999, or the comet technique.)

```
def events(request):
    def generate_events():
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(2)
            yield " " * 1024
            yield "This is some text.\n"
    return HttpResponse(generate_events())
```

Now, I'd like to detect when the user cancels the loading of the page, since there is no point in sending more data. Ideally, there would be something like:

```
if not request.is_alive():
    return
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you can do that from the server-side. But I'm sure you could use JavaScript to get some decent results. The "stream" will die when the JS stops asking for stuff from the server like in the case of a cancelled request.